# Why Sqlite cannot return result set with utf8 values in wp8

Tags: c#, sqlite, windows-phone-8

I have been struggling with the result of a simple query which returns result in sqlite manager, but not in wp8 app.

I have very simple view:

```
CREATE VIEW "BookmarkDetail" AS   SELECT b.BookmarkID, b.ChapterID, b.AyaID, c.TName, c.SuraName SuraName, a.Aya FROM Bookmark b inner join Chapter c on c.ChapterID = b.ChapterID
inner join ArabicText a on a.AyaID = b.AyaID and a.ChapterID = b.ChapterID
```

This returns result in sqlite manager

```
select * from BookmarkDetail
```

Calling the same from wp8 app with below code doesn't return any result.

```
public List<BookmarkDetail> getBookmarkDetail()
{
    return dbConn.Table<BookmarkDetail>().ToList();
}

public List<BookmarkDetail> BookmarkDetail
{
   get 
      {return getBookmarkDetail();} //This returns zero record
}
```

After some search, I find out that the columns "SuraName and Aya" are unicode (Arabic) values. If I remove these two columns from view definition, than the query returns result in both sqlite manager and wp8. If I add those two columns the query returns result in sqlite manager but not in wp8.

I didn't understand why wp8 cannot return result from such queries?
Do I need to change the collation of columns in view? If yes, How can I do it in sqlite?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I find the answer for this. I am sending the answer here maybe other may face such problem in sqlite.

When we create a table with primary key and auto increment, the auto increment value is stored in `sqlite_sequence` table. If you open .sqlite database file with any database valid database tool you would see this table.

If your table which has unicode data (column) and is not in this list, you should added. This solved my problem!!